# Specifying two different sort orders for a mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a query that sorts a numeric column in descending order. This column (`YTD%` in attached picture) is a mix of both positive and negative numbers. `ORDER BY ytd DESC` displays the data with highest positive values first and so on.
I however want to order the column in descending order (so the positive numbers come before the negatives), but with the numbers starting from least positive to highest and least negative to highest negative. So 1.50, 5.10, 7.10 etc.

[image: image showing current sort order]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple keys and expressions in the `order by`:

```
order by (ytd > 0) desc,  -- put positive numbers first
         ytd asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want exactly, you could do

```
ORDER BY
    SIGN(ytd) DESC,
    ABS(ytd) ASC
```

to get first all positive numbers from lowest to highest value and then all negative numbers from least negative to most negative, with any possible zeroes in between those.
In other words,

```
1
3
3
5
6
0
-3
-8
-10
```

If you want to have the zeroes come *before* the positive numbers, use

```
ORDER BY
    SIGN(SIGN(ytd) + 1) DESC,
    ABS(ytd) ASC
```

which would yield

```
0
1
3
3
5
6
-3
-8
-10
```

---

Should you want the negative and positive values intermingled, sorting just by their absolute value, just use

```
ORDER BY
    ABS(ytd) ASC,
    ytd DESC
```

which would yield

```
0
1
3
-3
3
5
6
-8
-10
```